# Send a file from Spring MVC controller to another Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 4 MVC RESTful web services application that needs to send a binary file to another Spring 4 MVC RESTful web services application.

I would like this to be done over HTTP in the same way as if the first Spring MVC application was instead a web client doing the upload.

Is this possible to do?

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like your question is *how can I consume the web service for X application* (regardless if the web service is implemented using Spring MVC or another technology).

Comment: The fact that the destination is a Spring MVC controller is irrelevant: the data will transfer using HTTP. So you want the source controller to also be an HTTP client. Look at the Spring `RestTemplate`class. But having the source controller do this directly is a bad design; it should be doing only MVC things. It should delegate to aservice layer.

Comment: @dimitrisli I disagree.  Raedwald wasn't suggesting to do the work completely outside of Spring MVC, only to separate duties and put this sort of code into a service layer.  I don't agree that it should be completely externalized.  It's perfectly legit design to make service calls from a service layer.  If not, 2/3 of the internet wouldn't exist.

Comment: @CodeChimp you are right. I've deleted my comment